# Creating shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I start with Create New Shapefile Layer, I give it a name and then select Polygon.
I then create my Polygon shape, its all good to this point. I now show a polygon with an outline and light red fill. From here I get stuck. I cant change the fill or do anything else with it. I think I'm missing a step.b

Comment: did you save the file? can you change the symbology of existing layers?

Comment: that sounds like you clicked the polygon with the identify-tool.  It sometimes happens that it keeps 'selected', even after closing the pop-up window.  Just click outside your polygon

Answer (score 4):

Check out the official getting started in the QGIS docs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#sample-session-loading-raster-and-vector-layers

Comment: I reviewed the documentation.  Also when I delete the layer, the polygon that I created still stays on the screen.  I can't delete it.

Answer (score 3):

This light red polygon is the one that is being created. It would typically be converted to a "normal" polygon once you are done creating it. To end its creation, make a right click.
Once it is a "normal" polygon, you can style it etc.

If an issue occurs before the polygon is completed, the red temporary polygon might stick to the map. It is not yet part of the layer and will remain on the screen. You would have to edit the layer again and the properly end the polygon.

Here is a scenario to reproduce it: create a new layer (could be a temporary scratch layer), start editing, add a new polygon, left click a few location then go to `stop editing` (without having made a right click to properly finish the drawing). The light red polygon will be shown.

Click `start editing` again, click `add feature` and the drawing of the faulty polygon will **resume**. Make a right click to properly finish its drawing. The polygon is now using the layer style that you can control.