# Problem with create line tool in QGIS, creates an undeletable line that is not part of any layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, vector

I was attempting to edit a shapefile layer in QGIS. I used the "create line tool" and started to sketch out a shape. I didn't like how it was turning out and tried to cancel it by pressing "escape" the line was left in place and now I can't delete it. It can't be selected with the vertex tool and especially strangely doesn't appear to be part of any layer. I can literally deselect every layer of my project and the line is still there. Also this happens every time I use the "create line tool".

Please help.

Comment: You will need to properly finish/delete the line: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315428/84870

Comment: Have you tried to close and open again your project?

Comment: Perhaps you created a line annotation? You can create annotation layers, or single annotations which are not associated with any layer. To delete it, you need to activate the Modify Annotations tool. Then you can select the annotation and hit the delete key.

Comment: It was the annotations one thanks!